# Recently viewed items widget view should be like product listing / category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, widget

I have created recently viewed widget, and added this in product view page, but the product view I want is to be like as it is displaying on prodcut listing page/category product listing page.
how could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: The problem has been solved, as i used report/product_veiwed.phtml file in my theme folder from base, and i strucured that file as product view page.
Is this right solution?

Comment: That sounds right :). Could you post an answer here and mark it as correct so others can benefit from your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the viewed product in the content of product page you can do it properly in **xml** like this:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="block/type" name="name.block" template="path to template.phtml"/> <!-- the recently viewed block -->
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then go `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`then put this where you want to display theme:

```
<?php echo this->getBlockHtml('name.block'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="container container--wide recently-viewed-section">
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
<div class="group-header">
    <div class="group-heading">
      <?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Items') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
      <ol class="product-grid" id="recently-viewed-items">
          <?php foreach ($_products as $product): ?>
              <li class="product-grid_item product-tile">
                  <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                    <div class="quickview"><button class="button button--s button--inverted">Quick View</button></div>
                      <picture class="pimg1">
                          <source srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(290, 290); ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                          <img srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(130, 130); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image')); ?>">
                      </picture>
                      <picture class="pimg2">
                          <source srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(290, 290); ?>" media="(min-width: 400px)">
                          <img srcset="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(130, 130); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel($product, 'thumbnail')); ?>">
                      </picture>
                      <?php

                      $isNewProduct = Mage::helper('magefrontend')->isNewProduct($product);
                      ?>
                      <?php if ($isNewProduct): ?>
                          <ul class="badge-list">
                              <li class="badge-list_item badge-list_item--new">
                                  <?php echo $this->__('New'); ?>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                  </a>
                  <?php
                    $showMessage = false;
                    $tmpProduct = $product->load($product->getId());
                        foreach ($tmpProduct->getOptions() as $productSize) {
                            if($productSize->getTitle() == 'Size'){ // Use Your Size Option Title
                                $values = $productSize->getValues();
                                foreach ($values as $value){
                                    if($value->getTitle() == 'XL'){ // Use your option text to match
                                        $showMessage = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                  <?php if($showMessage): ?>
                      <div class="product-banner-box">
                          <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
                      </div>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <!-- <div class="product-banner-box">
                        <span class="plussize-banner">now in plus sizes</span>
                  </div> -->
                  <?php if ($product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                      <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($product, 'short'); ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>

                  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product, true); ?>
                  <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()): ?>
                      <a class="product-addwishlist" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($product); ?>">
                          <span class="trigger-icon icon-heart"></span>
                      </a>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                  <a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                      <?php
                      echo Mage::helper('magefrontend')->preventTypographicWidow(
                          $this->escapeHtml($product->getName())
                      );
                      ?>
                  </a>
                  <?php if ($product->isSaleable()): ?>

                  <?php else: ?>
                      <div class="availability">
                          <span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out Of Stock'); ?></span>
                      </div>
                  <?php endif; ?>


              </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>

          <li class="product-grid_item flex-ghost"></li>
          <li class="product-grid_item flex-ghost"></li>
          <li class="product-grid_item flex-ghost"></li>
          <li class="product-grid_item flex-ghost"></li>
      </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
</div>
```